# How to bind bropdown list in Razor View (If view is not bound with any model)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can anybody suggest me how bind a dropdown list in MVC Razor view. I am using MVC 4. I have a view that is not bound with any model class.

```
public class Util { 
   public List<EmployeeType> GetEmpTypes() {
     return (new List<EmployeeType>(){ 
        new EmployeeType(){ID=101, Text="Permanent"}, 
        new EmployeeType(){ ID=102, Text="Temporary"} 
     }); 
   } 
} 

public class EmployeeType { 
   public int ID { get; set; } 
   public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

I have this sample code. I am new to MVC Now after this I don't know how to bind the collection returned by `GetEmployeeTypes()` Method to a dropdown list

Comment: public class Util
    {

        public List<EmployeeType> GetEmpTypes()
        {


            return (new List<EmployeeType>(){ 
            new EmployeeType(){ID=101, Text="Permanent"},
            new EmployeeType(){ ID=102, Text="Temporary"}
        });
        }

    }

    public class EmployeeType
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }I have this sample code. I am new to MVC Now after this I don't know how to bind the collection retured by GetEmployeeTypes() Method to a dropdown list

Comment: I moved your code to the question.  In the future, when you are asked for more information, always edit your question to include the information rather than posting an additional comment.

Comment: I have update my answer.please take a look now :)

Comment: Thanks @MikeC , I am new to MVC and also new to stack-overflow community. But I will keep this in mind while posting question. Thanks for your kind support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your class with method**

```
public class Util { 
   public List<EmployeeType> GetEmpTypes() {
     return (new List<EmployeeType>(){ 
        new EmployeeType(){ID=101, Text="Permanent"}, 
        new EmployeeType(){ ID=102, Text="Temporary"} 
     }); 
   } 
}
```

---

**Your model class with properties**

```
public class EmployeeType { 
   public int ID { get; set; } 
   public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

---

**This is sample action**

```
public ActionResult ViewName()
{
   Util xxx=new Util();
   List<SelectList> SelectedItems =new  List<SelectList>();
   List<EmployeeType> items =xxx.GetEmpTypes();
   foreach (var t in items )
    {
          SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
          s.Text = t.Text;
          s.Value = t.ID;
          SelectedItems.Add(s);
    }
 ViewBag.xxxxx= SelectedItems;
 return view();
}
```

---

**In View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("xxxxx", new SelectList(ViewBag.xxxxx, "Text", "Value"))
```

---

> This above code just like a key, i don't tested for that code ran successfully. you can get some idea for how to bind dropdown from my code.

Comment: public class Util, this class belongs to Model section?

Answer (score 1):

I had a Class like this to get all EmployeeTypes

```
public class Util
{

    public List<EmployeeType> GetEmpTypes()
    {
        return (new List<EmployeeType>(){ 
        new EmployeeType(){ID=101, Text="Permanent"},
        new EmployeeType(){ ID=102, Text="Temporary"}
    });
    }
}

public class EmployeeType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller I have written code to get the List of Employee Types

```
Util obj = new Util();
        var v = obj.GetEmpTypes();
        ViewBag.EmployeeTypes = v;
        return View();
```

In the View I have written code to bind dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployeeTypes",new SelectList(ViewBag.EmployeeTypes,"ID","Text"));
```

Thanks @Ramesh Rajendran ( Now I understood the concept to bind dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

**strong text**you  should create the model selectlist like here:

```
public static List<EmployeeType> GetEmpTypes() {
     return (new List<EmployeeType>(){ 
        new EmployeeType(){ID=101, Text="Permanent"}, 
        new EmployeeType(){ ID=102, Text="Temporary"} 
     }); 
   } 
  public static SelectList GetMyEmpTypes
            {
                get { return new SelectList(GetEmpTypes(), "ID", "Text"); }
            }
```

then you access this method in dropdown list like

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name",yourProjectNameSpace.Util.GetMyEmpTypes())
```

**when you will submit your form then it value bidden with Name get post to controller.**

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary to bind with model class.you can receive the value on controller with the name that you have given in view like:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Name",yourProjectNameSpace.YourClass.GetEmpTypes())
```

Now you can recive the name value at controller like:

```
public ActionResult test(String Name)
{
 return view();
}
```

**and make your method static i.e GetEmpTypes() so that you can access it from view.**

Comment: Please delete this answer, bcs your another answer looking good